# How do you change the hover text on a pinned taskbar item in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have 2 icons for the different version of the same app. I would like to rename one of them for more clarity. Currently, on hovering over the taskbar pinned icons, I see it as App and App (1). How can this name be edited?

The solution given for Win7 didn't work for Win10. The linked question for Windows7 - [How do you change the hover text on a pinned taskbar item in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/776214/how-do-you-change-the-hover-text-on-a-pinned-taskbar-item-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Unpin the executable from taskbar if you have it pinned already
2. Create (in a temporary location) a shortcut to the executable that you would like to pin to the taskbar. Make sure that this shortcut is anywhere in your system but not inside the pinned items directory. Your documents folder or desktop will do just fine
3. Rename the shortcut to whatever value you want shown when you hover over it
4. Drag the shortcut and drop it onto the taskbar
5. Delete the shortcut from the temporary location