# Windows 7 no start menu folder in app data - user pinned

Tags: windows-7, icons, start-menu

I'm trying to resolve the problem detailed here: [Pin to taskbar icon gets (2) appended](https://superuser.com/questions/61615/pin-to-taskbar-icon-gets-2-appended)

It was all going well until I got here `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned`

but in the user pinned folder I don't have a Start Menu folder - I only have ImplicitAppShortcuts (which is empty) and TaskBar folders. Does anyone know where this StartMenu folder might be?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the start menu folder by clicking on the start button and then right-clicking on the 'All Programs' bar.  Then, select 'Open' and it will open your start menu folder. [I got it here.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6463/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-open-the-start-menu-folder-in-windows-7/)

Comment: That's not the same folder the OP is looking for. What you've pointed out is the location of the objects (mainly shortcuts) on the Start Menu itself, not the items the user has pinned to the Start Menu.

Answer (score 0):

The `StartMenu` folder in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned` doesn't get created until you've pinned at least one thing to that user's Start Menu.

Pin something to their Start Menu and it should be created automatically.

Comment: No - tried this but still not there. When I pin something to the start menu it has a number in parenthesis afterwards, which indicates that the icon has already been pinned (see link in OP). I'm trying to resolve this by removing them from the start menu folder but it's not there! Like I say I just have two folders here C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned - they are named 'ImplicitAppShortcuts' and 'Taskbar'.

Comment: @JonP Is this machine on a Domain?  Seems like you user profile (or parts of it) may have been redirected...?